# How to "promote" Internal application to higher level Organization?

Tags: mdm, airwatch

We're currently using AirWatch to deploy an internal enterprise iOS application.  The group deploying the application is set-up as a sub-organization in the parent (something like Parent -> R&D).  The R&D organization is only assigned a couple of devices from the parent organization (who has many devices).

The problem is that any Internal applications from the R&D team can't be assigned to devices at the Parent organization level (even by administrators in the Parent organization).

Is there some way that the R&D organization can have the ability to publish new versions of the application and also have it target all devices in the Parent organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been able to find a way around this by granting additional permissions ("Application Management") at the top level of the organization.

It seems as though it is not possible to distribute an app created by a child organization to the parent unless the account uploading the app is at the top level of the organization (and thus can see and assign to all devices).